# mid function to filter 3rd position in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 tables which share a common key call `polno`. I am trying to filter the Access query that is run to create a table if 3rd position of `polno` is either `C` or `E`.

Some `polno` start with 2 blanks followed by number or character:

```
   C123234
0324233
FFC032345 
FFE23425
```

`PNDBSC` is the table the polno should filter from.

I have tried to use `Mid` function to select only those with `C` or `E` in 3rd position, also tried to use `LIKE` but doesnt work.

```sql
Mid([pndbsc.frcpolno],1,3) = "  C"
```

```sql
LIKE "__C%"
```

Looking to get insight on correct way to achieve expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`LIKE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Like-Operator-B2F7EF03-9085-4FFB-9829-EEF18358E931) operator in MS Access with the following wildcard pattern:

```sql
pndbsc.frcpolno LIKE "??[CE]*"
```

You were close with your example:

```sql
LIKE "__C%"
```

But this looks to be SQL Server syntax.

Based on your sample data, here are the expected results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks will try it out.  when do you use ? and * instead of _ and %?

Comment: @RashmiPatel The wildcard operators will depend on the RDMS you are using, for example, whilst SQL Server uses underscores to represent a single character and a percent sign to represent any number of characters, the JET database engine in MS Access uses question marks & asterisks respectively.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, so I tried your suggested code but doesn't seem to work.  It still lists all the numbers.  I tried use Not Like to see if it would discard the 3rd position C and E's policy numbers but not working.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @RashmiPatel I have updated my answer with a demonstration - using your sample data I receive the expected results (note that your first record is prefixed with three spaces, not two). Perhaps your implementation contains other selection criteria causing the numerical records to be included.